# Split array into strings

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, curl

I am in the process of creating a website that ges informatin from an API that responds in JSON-format. I would like to execute the following command in PHP:

`exec('curl -v -u {client_id}:{client_secret} -d code="{authorization_code}" -d redirect_uri={redirect_uri} -d grant_type=authorization_code https://api.basespace.illumina.com/v1pre3/oauthv2/token', $token);`

This returns an array called `$token` which contains something of the following format:

`Array
(
    [0] => {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Authorization code is unknown for this application or an access token has already been issued for it."}
)`

In this example I would like to put the `error` and the `error_description` in seperate variables, for further processing. 
I already thought of using `substr()`, but the content of `$token` can vary, so I think that won't work... 
Is there another, more simple way to split the array?

Comment: json_decode didn't work ?

Comment: No, for some reason that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = json_decode($token[0], true); //not a very indicative name for JSON, 'token'
$error = $arr['error'];
$error_desc = $arr['error_description'];
```

Comment: Instead I would do ... $arr = json_decode($token[0]); ... since $token is an array. And drop the [0] from the rest.

Comment: Well it clearly does *something* - it turns a JSON-encoded string into an object or array. Do some debugging to see what it's returning for you. You can `print_r()` its result.

Comment: `print_r($token)` gives the output I gave in my question.

Comment: Also, if I try `$arr = json_decode($token[0]);`, everything after that is not executed and nothing is `echo`d anymore

Comment: All right, I think I found the problem. I changed your first line to `$arr = json_decode($token[0], true);` and now it works. Thanks!